# In Rails 4, how do I create a named scope that does GROUP_BY after parsing the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, join, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by, rails-activerecord

I have a tricky problem where I need to get a list of consumers, ordered from most to least number of "check ins". Naturally, I have a Consumer model and a CheckIn model. The idea is the a consumer can check in any number of times throughout the month. This scope is meant to act as a sort of leaderboard for who has the most checkins this month.

Here is what I attempted, but I think it's not working because the GROUP_BY is running before there conditions in WHERE. Perhaps I need some kind of subquery for the join but I'm not entirely sure what that would even look like.

```
class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_ins, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :promo_codes

  validates :email, :email => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  # TODO: validate email
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name

  scope :with_most_checkins_this_month, ->(num_to_show) {  select("consumers.*, count( check_ins.id ) AS check_ins_count").
      joins(:check_ins).
      where('check_ins.created_at >= ? AND check_ins.created_at <= ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_month, DateTime.now.end_of_month).
      group("consumers.id").
      order("check_ins_count DESC").
      limit(num_to_show) }
end
```

Comment: Why is not working? It seems to work for me. For each element you could access its counter. Example: `Customer.with_most_checkins_this_month(10).first['check_ins_count']`